# Access a property on an object from an array of keys

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6

I want to write a helper function to unpack a specific object property from each object in an array of objects. Sometimes this property will be top level, other times it will be nested an arbitrary number of levels. So the crux of this question is: how can I access an object property based on an array of key names of variable length?

I'm hoping for something like:

```
const func = (arrOfObjects, ...keys) {
    return arrOfObjects.map(object => {
        return object[keys[0]][keys[1]] ... [keys[N]];
    })
}
```

with example behaviour:

```
const input = [
    {a: b: {c: 10}},
    {a: b: {c: 11}},
    {a: b: {c: 12}}
]

console.log(func(input, 'a', 'b', 'c'))
// [10, 11, 12]
console.log(func(input, 'a', 'b'))
// [{c: 10}, {c: 11}, {c : 12}]
```

I feel like there has to be a nice ES6 wizardry solution but as yet haven't found it so any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers,

P

Comment: I would make a recursive function. However, is the input an **array** or an **object**? You are mapping an array of objects, apparently, though the question suggests an "object" from an **array of keys**.

Comment: Ah, I phrased the title that way as I think it's the technical crux of the question. Within the map I want to access an object property based on a keys array. I'll try to make it more clear.

Comment: The question is not really clear to me. Would you mind clarifying what you are trying to do with an example where you write what `output` you expect from an example `input` please?
On first sight I would also go about a recursive function that traverses your object/array until it hits the thing you are searching. But are you searching for keys in objects or their respective value?

Comment: Have edited again, hopefully clearer now.

Comment: @Batters All the objects in the `input` will have the same shape? By shape, I mean would they all have same level of nesting or it can be different?

Comment: Hmm, so is it always that `[1, 2, 3]` matches the nesting of the object: `{ 1: { 2: { 3: "foo" } } } }` ? Or is it random and could also be like: `{ 1: "foo", 4: { 2: "bar }, 5: { 6: { 3: "baz" } } }` and you would expect the output to be ["foo", "bar", "baz"] ? Because that makes a huge difference if the array matches the object nesting pattern or if it is random.

Comment: All input objects will have the same structure, and the keys match the nesting of the object.

Comment: So, when you say they match the nesting, does that mean they ALWAYS start at the first level, or not? Say, you have `{a: b: {c: 12}}` but pass `['b', 'c']` - would you expect nothing to return or to get `12`? Basically, do you want to start searching for where these appear or do you expect to use the supplied properties straight away?

Comment: They will always start on the first level. As shown in the question, the property should be accessed by `object[keys[0]][keys[1]] etc. [keys[n]]`

Comment: Based on your answers here, I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answers you gave me to my questions and your example. It seems as if the order will of the input will always match the objects nesting. So here is my solution:

```js
const func = (arrOfObjects, ...keys) => {
  return arrOfObjects.map(object => {
    let obj = object, integer = keys.length;
    for (let index = 0; index < integer; index++) {
      obj = obj[keys[index]];
      if(obj === undefined) break;
    }
    return obj;
  });
};

const input = [
  { a: { b: { c: 10 } } },
  { a: { b: { c: 11 } } },
  { a: { b: { c: 12 } } }
];

console.log(func(input, "a", "b", "c"));
// [10, 11, 12]
console.log(func(input, "a", "b"));
// [{c: 10}, {c: 11}, {c : 12}]
```

Unfortunately there is no such thing as the javascript magic you where expecting.
*Note: this code will not work when the order of the keys inside the object are nested at random depth. But for what you are trying to solve, this should work just fine. Also, I tried to preserve your initial code as good as possible*

Comment: Passing properties that don't match up with the objects can break the function - for example, if you do `func(input, "b", "c")`

Comment: That’s exactly what I was saying, but check the comments below his question. The usecase is clearly defined. €: added a break that will return undefined if input is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a short and easy solution using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const input = [
    {a: { b: {c: 10}}},
    {a: { b: {c: 11}}},
    {a: { b: {c: 12}}}
]


console.log(func(input, ['a', 'b', 'c']))
// [10, 11, 12]
console.log(func(input, ['a', 'b']))
// [{c: 10}, {c: 11}, {c : 12}]

function func(input, props) {
  return input.map(x => exctractByProps(x, props));
}

function exctractByProps(obj, props) {
  return props.reduce( 
    (acc, prop) => typeof acc === 'object' && prop in acc ? acc[prop] : undefined, 
    obj 
  )
}
```

The main logic is to grab all the properties passed in and then try to get the value corresponding to `obj[prop[0]][prop[1]][prop[2]]/* ... */[prop[n]]`. If the object has an odd shape that doesn't match up with `prop` (for example, an input of `{a: 1}, ['a', 'b']` or `{d: {c: 1}}, ['a', 'b']`) then the function returns `undefined`.

Comment: I've accepted an answer but this also seems to work for exactly what I wanted, thanks. Now that I see it, reduce makes total sense for this application

Answer (score 0):

If you supply the accessor like `[a, b, c[0], name]`, you can write a custom function which returns the value if found in a nested Object, otherwise returns undefined

```js
 let obj = {
   a: 1,
   b: 2,
   c: {
     d: 1,
     e: [{
       f: 3,
       g: [{
         z: 45
       }]
     }]
   }
 }
function findKeyFromPattern(obj, patternArr) {
  let value = obj;
  for(let i = 0; i < patternArr.length; i++) {
    const arrmatch = patternArr[i].match(/(\w+)\[(\d+)\]/);
    if(arrmatch) { // pattern matches and array accessor syntax
      value = value[arrmatch[1]];
      if(typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
        value = value[arrmatch[2]];
      } else {
        return;
      }
    } else {
      if(value[patternArr[i]]) {
        value = value[patternArr[i]];
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  return value;
}


console.log(findKeyFromPattern(obj, ['c', 'e[0]', 'g']));
console.log(findKeyFromPattern(obj, ['c', 'e[1]', 'g']))
```

Comment: `value = value[arrmatch[1]] || undefined;` is this really needed? If `value[arrmatch[1]]` returns `undefined` the OR is completely superfluous. If it returns a falsey value like `0` or `""` it would be turned into `undefined`.

Comment: `value = undefined; return;` but...why? `return` would return `undefined` already. Why set `value` to this when this won't matter on literally the next line?

Comment: @vlaz, Thanks for pointing out a few basic flaws, the above isn't a perfect solution and I am still working on refining it. It points out an approach though

Comment: `findKeyFromPattern({a: 1}, ["a"])` works and returns the expected value but  `findKeyFromPattern({a: 1, b: { c: 2 }}, ["c"])` returns `undefined`. Same if you pass `["b.c"]` as a second parameter. To be honest, I'm having trouble reading through and understanding the function so I started poking it with some input.

Comment: Oh, I got it `findKeyFromPattern({a: 1, b: { c: 2 }}, ["b", "c"])` works.

Comment: @vlaz the above method is based on the assumption that obj is an object that contains nested fields which can be arrays as well, however if you suppy the initial value as an array it would fail.

Comment: `findKeyFromPattern({a: 1, b: { c: 2, d:[1, 2] }}, ["b", "d[1]"])` would work similarly